# How to add content from file using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have main html document:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I have a content file (not the html document, just html code):

```
<div class="CodeRay">
<div class="code"><pre><span class="no">   1</span> require
....
</pre></div>
```

I want to add the content file to html document like here:

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="CodeRay">
            <div class="code"><pre><span class="no">   1</span> require
            ....
            </pre></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to use jQuery to accomplish this task? Also I need to run this site localy. Thanks.

**EDIT**: Locally means like this "file:///E:/Work/ReadTheCode/main.html"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.load()` function. The code would probably look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#content').load('contentFile.html');
});
```

If you need more info, [here is the link](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to jquery's load documentation.

Comment: Chrome says "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/Work/ReadTheCode/content/base.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." I think it's because of XMLHttpRequest crossdomain

Comment: Since you want to use it locally, the paths should be relative to the document.

Comment: Yeah, don't point to file:///E:/Work... say if your current HTML file is in the ReadTheCode folder, your load should look like this:  
`$('#content').load('content/base.html');`

Comment: I didn't make full path, it's a Chrome issue, in Firefox it works.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/load/