# How to change text from documents using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

So originally I had the following, which allowed me to change text on the click of a link:

```
<p id="message">Starting Text</p>
<a href="#" class="link">Show message #1</a><br>

<script>
   var test = 'test text';

   $(".link").click(function() {
      $("#message").text(test);
   });
</script>
```

How could I change this so the text is pulled from .txt documents?

Comment: Are these `.txt` documents on your own server?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6181121/489560).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those `.txt` documents are stored on the server you could use an AJAX call to retrieve the contents of them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".link").click(function() {
        $.get('/some_text_document.txt', function(result) {
            $("#message").text(result);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Further reading for you about jQuery and AJAX:

- [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text files are on your server, you should use the `load` jquery method.

```
var url = 'content/file.txt';

$(".link").click(function() {
   $("#message").load(url);
});
```